# Failed to pass value to handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to compare two values in template hence i have used handlebars helper as given below :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
    console.log(v1);console.log(v2);
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

My template code :

```
{{#ifCond item.id 1}}                           
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:0px;">                           
{{else}}
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:5px;">
{{/ifCond}}
```

But value of `item.id` is not getting pass to helper it showing its value as  "item.id".

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake in my above code?

Comment: And outputting the id works with `{{item.id}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend altering between markup with an if statement. I have done it myself and this is a brittle approach and not very concise. I would always try to use the helper `{{bind-attr}}` (the helper is called {{bindAttr}} in rc7 and below).

**CSS:**

```
row.margin-top{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="row" {{bindAttr class="item.isWithMargin:margin-top"}}>
```

This is not the most elegant approach, as you would have css specific logic in your model. **There fore you could iterate over your items and assign an itemController to each item and place the logic in this controller.**

```
{{#each item in controller itemController="yourItemController"}}
<!-- this would resolve to App.YourItemController -->
App.YourItemController = Ember.ObjectController({
  isWithMargin : function(){
    return this.get("model.id") == 1;
  }.property("model.id")
});
```

Comment: I am getting following error Uncaught Error: Could not resolve itemController: "HomeController" and 
unable to find solution.

Comment: And you declared an `App.HomeController`?

Comment: Yes HomeController is  controller for this route and route is HomeRoute.

Comment: Plz try starting with lowercase : 'homeController'

Comment: No,still i am getting Uncaught Error: Could not resolve itemController: "homeController"

Comment: Can you explain this with jsfiddle?

Comment: Oh my bad. Just set the property to `home`. I just discovered it myself when getting the fiddle to work: http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/WavM3/

Comment: Still i am getting  exception, i have update my code here http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/yTYtK/2/

Comment: Your code still does not work if i remove the itemController part. You have nested 4 {{#each}} in your template, but i only see 2 nested levels in your Astcart.Application model. Get it to work without the itemController and i can help you.

Comment: Yes sir, I have update code here http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/fQNRk/ if you remove itemController part it will show list of product name but with item controller part is throwing an exception.

Comment: I have corrected the fiddle and removed one level of {{#each}} and i guess its working the way you might want it. http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/fQNRk/1/
One additional hint: Never name a controller `IndexController`. It is a reserved name in Ember. You should only use this name if you really want to explicitly define the controller for your Index Route. But in your case, you want to use it as an arbitrary itemController. I renamed it therefore.